# Erro ao executar App no Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, app

Quando executo (tanto no emulador Android no PC, quanto no smartphone) o App retorna o seguinte erro:

```
<p>Installation failed with message Invalid File: C:\Users\Rubinho\AndroidStudioProjects\Let&amp;amp;amp;amp;apos;sFriend2\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.<p>
WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!<p>
Do you want to uninstall the existing application?**<p><p>
Na aba Run, fica da seguinte forma:<p>
**03/20 16:34:46: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r C:\Users\Rubinho\AndroidStudioProjects\Let&amp;amp;amp;amp;apos;sFriend2\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk C:\Users\Rubinho\AndroidStudioProjects\Let&amp;amp;amp;amp;apos;sFriend2\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk C:\Users\Rubinho\AndroidStudioProjects\Let&amp;amp;amp;amp;apos;sFriend2\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk C:\Users\Rubinho\AndroidStudioProjects\Let&amp;amp;amp;amp;apos;sFriend2\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk C:\Users\Rubinho\AndroidStudioProjects\Let&amp;amp;amp;amp;apos;sFriend2\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk C:\Users\Rubinho\AndroidStudioProjects\Let&amp;amp;amp;amp;apos;sFriend2\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk C:\Users\Rubinho\AndroidStudioProjects\Let&amp;amp;amp;amp;apos;sFriend2\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk C:\Users\Rubinho\AndroidStudioProjects\Let&amp;amp;amp;amp;apos;sFriend2\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk C:\Users\Rubinho\AndroidStudioProjects\Let&amp;amp;amp;amp;apos;sFriend2\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk C:\Users\Rubinho\AndroidStudioProjects\Let&amp;amp;amp;amp;apos;sFriend2\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk C:\Users\Rubinho\AndroidStudioProjects\Let&amp;amp;amp;amp;apos;sFriend2\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk C:\Users\Rubinho\AndroidStudioProjects\Let&amp;amp;amp;amp;apos;sFriend2\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk 
$ adb shell pm uninstall com.example.rubinho.letsfriend
Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565))
Error while Installing APKs
```

Comment: Desinstala o aplicativo atual (emulador/dispositivo) e executa novamente.

Comment: Nao tem aplicativo atual instalado

Comment: estou com o mesmo problema com alguns aplicativos

Comment: Rubinho, não sei com voce, mas para contornar o erro, eu consegui de 2 maneiras... aparentemente ficou um cache inexistente na memoria do emulador, a primeira opção que eu fiz foi importar o projeto para um outro projeto com nome diferente, e a outra foi criar um novo emulador...
tablet e outros afins funcionam perfeitamente

Comment: Tente dar um rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

a solução para mim foi a seguinte:

- Apaguei todos os arquivos apks da seguinte pasta **"SeuProjeto"\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices**
- Abri a aba **"Gradle projects"** e cliquei em **"refresh external project"**
- Por fim selecionei a opção **"Build"** e **"Rebuild Project"**

Não sei te dizer se foi a correta mas funcionou pra mim, espero que ajude.